# Use Mono for Windows in MonoDevelop for Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mono, monodevelop

I have a problem compiling c# code in Unity's MonoDevelop tool. I found in this question that I should download Mono for Windows and use that as default runtime in MonoDevelop.

[Compiling C# via Unity3D and MonoDevelop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22640833/compiling-c-sharp-via-unity3d-and-monodevelop/28913876#28913876)

But I can't figure out how to configure it as default runtime.

The answer says 'find the installed Mono release', which in my case is C:\Program Files (x86)\Mono But MonoDevelop keeps complaining about that it is not a valid a directory prefix. I also tried subdirectories \bin, \etc\mono\4.5, \include\mono2.0\mono, \lib\mono and \share\mono2-0\mono, and a lot more but none are accepted.

Can someone tell me which directory I should use?

Thanks.

Comment: It must be in the folder **Unity\MonoDevelop\bin**. File **MonoDevelop.exe**

Comment: Unfortunately that directory is also not accepted as a valid directory where mono is installed.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, Monodevelop is not associated with Unity. 
Go under Edit -> Preferences -> External Tools and see if Monodevelop is selected as external script editor.and 
1-install jxpiinstall
2-mono-4.0.3-gtksharp-2.12.26-win32-0.msi
3-XamarinStudio-5.9.6.23-0.msi
[image]